# Reloading a gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am able to reload an addon with a single root card with `CardService.newNavigation().popToRoot().updateCard(card)`.

However I could not find how to reload an addon with multiple root cards.

It would be better if google provides a `CardService` method for the same.

Comment: If you'll check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781933/how-can-i-relaunch-update-refresh-the-card-again-using-apps-script/50713727), it was mentioned that there is this kind of feature request. To see the full details, visit this site: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/71466051](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71466051)

Comment: Yeah, i saw that.  In case, if someone comes with a work around, it would be much better.